# Can I gift a game via the PlayStation Network?

Tags: psn

Is it possible to "gift" a game (e.g., *Castle Crashers*) to someone through the PlayStation Network?  I don't have a PS3 but was considering buying *Castle Crashers* as a gift for a friend so that we could play co-op.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is currently no gifting option, available via the PSN.

But, there are a few other options you can use:

- Buy the game via [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0040X3LYK), and get a online game code, which you then can give to your friend.
- Buy a PSN gift card, and give it to him.

Comment: Really?  Bummer.  Thanks for the alternatives, though.

Comment: Yep, I really wish the PSN had that feature tho, it's so useful. Although, the Amazon option works fairly well, for that purpose.

Comment: Be interesting to see if this becomes available once steam becomes available for the PSN.