# How to buy free game?

Tags: psn, ps-vita

I had PS+ account with Gravity Rush purchased (PS+ free game). My PS+ will end in 3 month, but last month i saw Gravity Rush in 0.99 USD sale and i want to buy it since my PS+ will be over soon. I can't find the "purchase" button because i already purchase that game (as free game). I already use the website and i still can't find the "purchase" button.

How can i purchase my PS+ free game which is already purchased ? Golden week sale is near and i still in my PS+ subscription.

Comment: No. You can't "buy" a game if its on your rental subscription on PS Plus. You'd have to wait for PS+ to expire before you can purchase it.

Comment: @Wallyx there is a way i can cancel that PS+ ? i just want to buy them.

Comment: Im not a real PS3 user I did never cancel the subscription but i think this may work http://faq.en.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5035/~/how-to-cancel-a-subscription

Comment: @Wallyx i already read it, but it's only cancel auto renewal.

Comment: I do not know anything about PSN. Just a general idea: Could you purchase the game with a secondary account as a gift to your main account?

Comment: @MichaelK [This answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/15640/91079) say you can't gift to another account. The discount happen at PSN store not in amazon store .

Comment: You can't gift purchase in the PSN store, and if you bought a DL code from a retailer, PSN would tell you that the code can not be claimed as you already own the title.

Answer (score 1):

In specific response to the details of your question there are two answers:

1) No. In that you would have to cancel your PSN+ membership, but cancelling the membership blocks you from the discount. If you renew your membership you may regain access to prior downloads, which would again block purchase since it is already "purchased". (I suppose there is a sketchy chance that you'll loose all your old licenses if you renew a cancelled acount, so in that untested case this might become a Yes).

2) Yes. Create a new PSN account with a new PSN+ subscription. Wipe your Vita clear and loose all of your old user data. Add the new PSN account and purchase the game. ...the side effects of this approach in my mind would equate to a No rather than a Yes, but it's all about how desperate you are.

Personally, I just went and bought the physical copy. Once it's patched to the same version as the PSN download. You can transfer your save data between copies on a PC from the Content Manager backup folder.

Answer (score -2):

### How to Access Your Purchased games on PSvita

Go the the Playstation Store and on the right hand bottom corner is a little bubble (...), click on that, a new menu will flyout with the option of "download list". Here are all your downloads/aka purchases, you can download from your entire collection including games you "bought" when they were free from Plus.
[image: Playstation Store Vita - Extra options "download list"]

### What Happens to your store view when you buy an IGC "Free" PS+ title

"Purchase" doesn't show up for you anymore because you already own the game.
Take for example this screenshot of my account, I "bought" Yakuza 4 while it was available for Free as a IGC, I still have PS+ membership, when I visit the store, even on the web, the ability to "purchase" is absent and only the ability to "download" - this is a bit of evidence that shows you have to NOT be a PS+ member to get the option to "purchase" an IGC title you "bought".

[image: Playstation Store - Yakuza 4 - profile is PS+ member and "bought" IGC]

If you do not renew your membership, your access to download "Instant Game Collection" games will be revoked. It's not 100% clear from the [Playstation Plus FAQ](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/Forum-Frequently-Asked-Questions/PlayStation-Plus-FAQ/td-p/37512373), but based on this question/answer we can see that you have the option to purchase the game but it seems to be only AFTER your membership expires:

> Q: What happens to the games and Add-Ons I downloaded free through a PS Plus membership, and I decide to not renew my membership?
>
> A: If you do not renew your PS Plus membership, you will not be able to access previous free games downloaded with Plus. If you have purchased Add-Ons for a game you received free in Plus, and it requires said free game to play it, you will not be able to access these Add-Ons if you choose not to renew your membership. However, if you decide to re-activate your membership, you will once again be able to play all games downloaded from the Instant Game Collection along with all purchased DLC for these games. ***Alternatively, you may also purchase the specific game*** to access any purchased Add-Ons for the game as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. When you get a game for free through PlayStation Plus's "Instant Game Collection" you don't own a copy of the game, you're just renting it. Once your PS+ subscription expires the game is removed your collection and you can no longer play it. On the other hand if you buy a game through PSN with a PS+ discount, it remains a part of your collection even after your PS+ subscription exipres.

Comment: @RossRidge ahh I see, my mistake, I failed to see the part about how the OP doesn't want to continue PS+ , I'll amend my answer.

Comment: My condition now is i'm still on PS+ subscription when i want purchase that game. If there is some way to force expire the PS+ membership this method will worked greatly.

Comment: @SeptianPrimadewa it seems to me that your circumstance is a bit unique due to the fact that you want to be able to purchase this game within a window of a special offer, but that window closes by the time your PS+ membership expires. To be frank, the fact that you purchased this IGC on PS+ and now will miss the discounted price to be able to play it without PS+ is bad luck. You're probably better off contacting customer support to see if they can help you purchase the discounted game while you are still a PS+ subscriber.