# Can I gift a game on PSN?

Tags: psn

As the title suggest, I'd like to buy a game for someone on the PSN and send it to them or allow them to download it, is this possible?

This question has already been asked here:

> [Can I gift a game via the PlayStation Network?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15639/can-i-gift-a-game-via-the-playstation-network)

And the answer was *No*. But that was 4 years ago.

I'm hoping something has changed since then.

Comment: @Frank I mentioned that question in my question. It was asked and answered 4 years ago, I'm asking if anything has changed in that time. Is that not allowed?

Comment: The question has already been asked.  Is there any reason to think that might have changed, or that the answers might be wrong?  Questions are to withstand the test of time, and answers hopefully updated as needed, not be re-asked.

Comment: @Frank Technology moves quickly and 4 years is a long time. But nevermind, I'll seach elsewhere on the web.

Comment: If you can't find any ways to gift something on PSN, then I would say the other question still stands.

Comment: I've answered it without looking at the other question, so my answer may be a duplicate but well it answers this question.

Answer (score 1):

According to what I've found out by trying an googling. It's still not possible, there are some workarounds but you can't actually gift a game on the psn.

Possible workarounds:

- Buy the game and send him the code
- Give him money so he can buy the game
- Buy a PSN card with x money on it and give it to him

Those are the only ways I can think of or I can find of which you can give your friend a game on the playstation.

Comment: Doing it indirectly, by giving the other party some form of currency they can use to fund the purchase, also allows them to use the currency to fund other purchases that might suit them better.

Comment: I said possible workarounds, not things that could definitely work